# Style dijit.form.Select drop down menu

Tags: forms, select, dojo

How can I style a `dijit.form.Select` **drop down** menu if a use the HTML markup.

```
<select id="sourceselect"   dojoType="dijit.form.Select" style='width:200px' onChange="changeDetected();">
</select>
```

To make it clear it want to style the drop down menu that is filled with the content. I want to change the height of that menu and have a scroll bar if the height is exceeded.

I am using Dojo version 1.6. Here is a Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/NH7dd/.

**Edit: Why the minuses?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu that is generated by Dojo is placed in the root of the DOM node. It's a common mistake that the menu is somehow relative positioned towards the textfield, but it isn't.

If you wish to change the style of the menu, then you could use the following CSS selector:

```css
div[dijitpopupparent="sourceselect"] > .dijitMenu {
    /** Your CSS */
}
```

The reason this works is because the menu is wrapped inside a `dijit/popup`. This popup allows displaying/hiding the menu and as you can see it has an attribute `dijitpopupparent` which has the original ID of the field.

I also updated your JSFiddle, which now looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/RHLFz/). But I don't really recommend changing the behavior of the menu like this, since you might mess up the original functionality/behavior of the combobox. I mean, right now I have problems going to certain values because one "scroll tick" already passes a value. With the updated style I can't even properly select "2" anymore.

---

**EDIT:** In the updated JSFiddle the scrollbar will always be visible, if you want the scrollbar only to appear when there are more options, then change `overflow-y: scroll` to `overflow-y: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property for maxHeight.

```
<select id="sourceselect"   
dojoType="dijit.form.Select"
data-dojo-props="maxHeight: 200" 
style='width:200px' 
onChange="changeDetected();">
</select>
```

Also, the newer syntax for dojo is "data-dojo-type" instead of "dojoType".

Here is JSFiddle showing the maxHeight property. (I used dojo 1.9, but maxHeight is available in 1.6)
http://jsfiddle.net/NH7dd/17/

Comment: The argument for maxHeight is supposed to be an integer. I've edited my answer. The reason your fiddle is not working is because you aren't loading dojo correctly. The select on your fiddle is just a regular select not a dojo select.