# How to style the drop down menu of a programmatic dijit.form.select

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, css-selectors, dijit.form

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221006/style-dijit-form-select-drop-down-menu)

The difference is that there is no `id` in my `dijit.form.Select`. The id is the one assigned by dojo itself. So how do I achieve the result as in the linked question?

**Edit**: I can add custom class to the `dijit.form.Select`

One method that I could figure out was to use something like :

```
div[dijitpopupparent ^= "dijit_form_Select"] > .dijitMenu{
   ...
}
```

which will work like a regex for the CSS. But it will apply the CSS to all the `dijit.form.Select` elements in the entire application which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that you can add a specific class to your `dijit.form.Select` , by exemple add `.myClass` (we're going to use it later)
then create the specific css which will be applied to the div popup

**CSS**

```
.stylePopup {
    max-height: 25px;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    /* other styles tuff ... */
}
```

then you you'll add this class to the popup div of the `dijit.form.Select` whose have the above class programmaticly ,
by looping over all the dijits than if a dijit have a "`myClass`" class then append to it's popup div the `stylePopup` class
(the code is in Dojo AMD style 1.7+)

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/dom-class"
], function(
    ready,
    registry,
    dom,
    array,
    domClass
) {

ready(function() {
  var selectDijitClass = "myClass";
  var classToApply = "stylePopup";

  array.forEach(registry.toArray(),function(widget){
    console.log(widget);
    if(widget.declaredClass === "dijit.form.Select" && widget.class === selectDijitClass){
      console.log(registry.byId(widget.id+"_menu").domNode.parentNode);
      widget.on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(dom.byId(this.id+"_dropdown")){
            if(!domClass.contains(dom.byId(this.id+"_dropdown"), classToApply))
                domClass.add(dom.byId(this.id+"_dropdown"),classToApply);
        }

      });
    }
  });

});  
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfTXC/285/)

Comment: What you are saying is true and valid only for the example you mentioned. But in my case there are many more widgets and the widget of `dijit.form.Select` and `dijitPopup` are **NOT** adjacent. They are very very much separated.

Comment: why not add an Id, otherwise you have to make a programmatic solution !

Comment: As far as I can tell is, in the postCreate you are iterating the desired dijit.form.Select elements using the class and applying class to the dijitPopup widgets associated with them. Right? I also thought of this, but it is not a desirable solution for me. Anyways, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Yes , I'm doing this , but not in postcreate , just when you click on the select .
I agree that this is not suitable , but in you can't apply style on specific select without adding a specific ID for every one or use a programmatic method , greets :)

Comment: Replying to your earlier comment about why id cannot be added. It is because there are lots of widgets being created programmatically and there is no point in assigning ids to all the widgets, considering it is a single page application. We are revamping our application and avoiding assignment of ids to widgets.

Thanks for your help and suggestions! :)